# Need help understanding a proof on if a homomorphism in $\textbf{Grp}$ is not onto then it is not epimorphic

Tags: group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

### Background information

Prove that if $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism with $\phi(G)=M\neq H,$ then $\phi$ is not an epimorphism in $\textbf{Grp}.$  [Hint: If $M$ has only 2 cosets in $H$, take $K=H/M,$ and define $\psi, \psi':H\rightarrow K$ by $\psi(h)=[h]$ and $\psi'(h)=e_K.$ If not, take $K$ to be the group of all permutations of $H.$  Choose $3$ different cosets $M, Mh', Mh''$ of $M$ in $H,$ and define $\sigma$ in $K$ by $\sigma(xh'')=xh', \sigma(xh')=xh''$ for $x\in M,$ while otherwise $\sigma(h)=h.$  Define $\psi,\psi':H\rightarrow K$ by $\psi(h)=$ left multiplication by $h$, and $\psi'(h)=\sigma^{-1}\psi(h)\sigma.$  Then in either case $\psi\phi=\psi'\phi$ but $\psi\neq \psi'.$]

### Questions

I don't understand how $\psi \neq \psi'.$

According to the proof, suppose $h\in H\setminus M,$ then $\psi(xh'')=hxh'',$ and $\psi'(xh'')=(\sigma^{-1}\psi\sigma)(xh'')=\sigma^{-1}\psi\sigma(xh'')=\sigma^{-1}\psi(xh')=\sigma^{-1}(hxh'')$

But does $\sigma^{-1}(hxh'')=\sigma^{-1}(h)\sigma^{-1}(xh'')?$ (not sure if this is correct or how to justify it?) So that $\sigma^{-1}(h)=h$ and $\sigma^{-1}(xh'')=xh'.$  Hence $\sigma^{-1}(hxh'')=hxh'.$  Hence $\psi'(xh'')\neq \psi(xh'').$

Am I understanding the proof correctly?  Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't make any sense of your explanation. $\psi(xh'')$ is not equal to $xh''$, it is the permutation of $H$ defined by left multiplication by $xh''$. To show that $\psi \ne \psi''$, note that $\psi(h')(e_H) = h'$, but $\psi'(h')(e_H) = h''$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I corrected the typo.  It should be $\psi(xh'')=hxh''.$.    Can I ask if $\sigma^{-1}(hxh'')=\sigma^{-1}(h)\sigma^{-1}(xh'')?$  If so, do I use the notion of group action to justify it.

Comment: $\psi(xh'') = hxh''$ still makes no sense. $\psi(xh'')$ is not an element of $H$, it is a permutation of the underlying set of $H$. Also $\sigma$ is not a group homomorphism,it too is a permutation of the underlying set of $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt it says $\psi(h)=$ left multiplication by $h$ means $\psi(x)=hx,$ so $\psi(xh'')=hxh''$  Also, why is it that $\psi$ is a permutation of the underlying set of $H$?  I thought only $\sigma$ denotes permutation.  I am trying to understand the hint and I asked couple of math grad students, they were not able to make sense of it.  I also posted the contrapositive version of this statement from another post, apparently Arthuro from the comment in that post told me I won't have a chance in hell in understanding the proof until I understand group actions.

Comment: A permutation is a special kind of function, namely a bijection from a set to itself. The set can be any set. Also, the symbol you use to express a permutation can be any symbol; you are not restricted to the symbol $\sigma$.

Comment: @LeeMosher the contrapositive statement I [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719742/need-help-understanding-a-proof-on-if-a-homomorphism-in-textbfgrp-is-not-on?noredirect=1#comment9998518_4719742) here.  For both proofs, I asked two math grad students about it, they both were equally confused.  I know I am supposed to fill in the gaps, but I am not able to, and they were not able to either, that is why I am asking what is confusing me for both on here.

Comment: $\psi(h) = $ left multiplication by $h$ does not mean $\psi(x)=hx$. It means that $\psi(h)$ is the permutation of $H$ defined by left multiplication by $h$. In other words $\psi(h)(x) = hx$ for all $x \in H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt how does $\psi'(h)=\sigma^{-1}\psi(h)\sigma?$ and from there $\psi\neq \psi'?$

Comment: $\psi'(h) = \sigma^{-1} \psi(h) \sigma$ is the definition of $\psi'$. I will answer the question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\psi(h)$ is a permutation of $H$ defined by $\psi(h)(x) = hx$ for $x \in H$.

$\sigma$ is also defined as a permutation of $H$, and $\psi'(h) = \sigma^{-1}\psi(h)\sigma$ is defined to be the composite of the three permutations $\sigma^{-1},\,\psi(h),\,\sigma$.

I claim that $\psi'(h') \ne \psi(h')$, which proves that $\psi \ne \psi'$. To prove this, we have to show that $\psi(h')$ and $\psi'(h')$ are different permutations of $H$, and to do that it is enough to show that they have different actions on some point of $H$.

Let's consider their actions on the identity element $e_H$ of $H$.

We have $\psi(h')(e_H) = h'$, and $$\psi'(h')(e_H) = \sigma^{-1}(\psi(h')(\sigma(e_H))) = \sigma^{-1}(\psi(h')(e_H)) = \sigma^{-1}(h') = h'' \ne \psi(h')(e_H).$$
So $\psi(h') \ne \psi'(h')$ as claimed.

Comment: is it because $\psi'(h)$ being equal to left multiplication by $h$, that means it is consider to be a left regular representation, another words a group action?  Then $h\cdot x=hx=\psi(h)(x),$ where $h\in H, x\in M.$  For the cosets, we also have $h\cdot M=hM,$ and $h\cdot x=hxh^{-1}$ But how do I relate to $\psi'(h)=\sigma^{-1}\psi(h)\sigma,$  I assume that $\sigma$ is also a left regular representation.  I learned about left regular representation from Hungerford's undergraduate Abstract Algebra text.  In there, he uses the notation: ... .

Comment: ...For all $a\in G$, $\phi_a(x)=ax.$  He also uses the notation $\phi(x)(a)$ to mean $\phi_a(x).$  I was reading up on group actions and trying to figure out which notation is what the whole day.  My apologies for my late reply.

Comment: $\psi$ is the left regular representation of the group $H$. But $\sigma$ is not a representation at all, it is a single permutation.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot make any sense of what you write, or what it has to do with my answer. I have answered the question. If there is some step that you do not understand then let me know.

Comment: I want to know if $\psi'(h)=\sigma^{-1}\psi(h)\sigma$ is consider a left regular representation of the group $H$ from the way it is defined and also because after rearranging by conjugation, then $\psi(h)=\sigma\psi'(h)\sigma^{-1}.$  Sorry, I delete the comment since I made some LaTex error and it was not displaying my comment properly.

Comment: It's *equivalent* to the left regular representation. That is a technical term meaning exactly that it is defined from the regular representation by conjugating by a fixed permutation - which is $\sigma$ in this case.

Comment: how did you figure out from the proof that $\sigma$ is not a regular representation.   I thought every permutation group satisfies the two properties for regular representation.

Comment: As I said earlier, $\sigma$ is not a representation, and it is not a group, it is a single permutation.You seem to be very confused about what all these words mean! Your sentence "I thought every permutation group satisfies the two properties for regular representation" is just nonsense.  I am sorry but I cannot answer any more questions unless you think there is a mistake in the proof.

Comment: I think when I saw "take K to be the group of all permutations of H", I thought $\sigma$ is a permutation group.  I just got confused.