# Need help understanding the proof that "A Group Epimorphism is Surjective."

Tags: group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation

The following is from the paper "A Group Epimorphism is Surjective" by C.E. Linderholm

The proof of the proposition is the contrapositive of the statement from this
[post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719742/need-help-understanding-a-proof-on-if-a-homomorphism-in-textbfgrp-is-not-on)  which have I have questions about.

### Background information

> Let $\phi: F\rightarrow G$ to mean that $F$ and $G$ are groups and $\phi$ is a homomorphism defined on $F$ and taking values in $G$. If $\psi:G\rightarrow H$ the composite homomorphism from $F$ to $H$ is written $\phi\psi.$  If $x\in F$ the image under $\phi$ is written $(x)\phi.$  A homomorphism $\psi$ that cancels on the right in every equation $\phi_1\psi=\phi_2\psi$ is a monomorphism.  If $\psi:G\rightarrow H$ then $\psi$ is a monomorphism if for each group $F$ and for each pair $\phi_1, \phi_2$ of homomorphism from $F$ to $G$ such that $\phi_1\psi=\phi_2\psi,$ the equation $\phi_1=\phi_2$ holds.  A homomorphism $\phi$ that cancels on the left in every equation $\phi_1\psi=\phi_2\psi$ is an epimorphism. If $\phi:F\rightarrow G$ and if an inverse homomorphism $\psi$ from $G$ to $F$ exists - i.e., one such that $(x)\phi\psi=x$ for each element $x$ of $F$ and $(y)\psi\phi=y$ for each element $y$ of $G$- then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.   We prove that "A Group Epimorphism is Surjective".
>
> Proof:  Let $\phi$ be an epimorphism from a group $G$ to a group $H,$ and let $A$ be the image subgroup.  We must show that $A=H.$  To do this we construct two homomorphism $\psi_1,\psi_2$ from $H$ to a group $K$ such that $\phi\psi_1=\phi\psi_2,$ and we use the resulting equation $\psi_1=\psi_2$ to prove that $A=H.$
>
> Let $H/A$ be the set of all right cosets of $A;$ let $A'$ be something that is not a right coset of $A,$ and let $S$ be the set $H/A\cup\{A'\}.$  Let $K$ be the group of all permutations (bijections) of $S.$  If $h,h_1,h_2\in H$ and if $Ah_1$ and $Ah_2$ are the same coset, then $A(h_1h)$ and $A(h_2h)$ are the same coset, and hence the function from $A/H$ to $A/H$ that sends $Ah'$ to $A(h'h)$ is well defined.  It is easily seen to be bijective.  (in fact its inverse is given by $Ah'\rightarrow Ah'h^{-1}.$) If $A'$ is sent to itself, this defines a bijection of $S,$ which we write $(h)\psi_1.$  The function $\psi_1$ from $H$ to $K$ so defined is easily seen to be a homomorphism.  Let $\sigma$ be the permutation of $S$ that interchanges $A$ and $A'$ and leaves everything else fixed, and if $h\in H$ write $(h)\psi_2$ for the composite permutation $\sigma^{-1}((h)\psi_1)\sigma.$  Then the function $\psi_2$ is the composition of $\psi_1$ with an inner automorphism of $K,$ and hence is a homomorphism from $H$ to $K$.
>
> If $a\in A,$ then $(a)\psi_1$ leaves both $A$ and $A'$ fixed, and $\sigma$ leaves every other element of $S$ fixed  Hence $\sigma$ and $(a)\psi_1$ commute, and $(a)\psi_1=\sigma^{-1}((a)\psi_1)\sigma.$  Since $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ agree on the range of $\phi,$ the equation $\phi\psi_1=\phi\psi_2$ holds.  Since $\phi$ is an epimorphism, $\psi_1=\psi_2.$  Hence $(h)\psi_1$ commutes with $\sigma$ for each element $h$ of $H.$  Since $(h)\psi_1$ leaves $A'$ fixed and $\sigma$ interchanges $A'$ and $A.$ It follows that $(h)\psi_1$ leave $A$ fixed.  Since $(h)\psi_1$ sends $A$ to $Ah,$ it follows that $h\in A.$  Since $h$ was an arbitrary element of the group $H,$ it follows that $A=H$ and $\phi$ is surjective.

Note: where it says the function from $A/H$ to $A/H$, should it not be $H/A$ to $H/A?$

### Questions

There are some points about the above proof I am not clear on.

I understand that $A=\phi(G)$, but do the set $K$ consist of both the permutations $\sigma$ and $(h)\psi_1.$

For the function $(h)\psi_1$, it is defined as $(h)\psi_1:H\to K$ but what about at various places where it says it sends $A\to Ah,$ $A'$ to itself.  In terms of elements evaluated by $\psi_1$, what is the difference between when it sends $A'$ to itself versus $(a)\psi_1.$  Earlier in the proof, it already states that $(h)\psi_1$ sends $A'$ to itself, but $(a)\psi_1$ leaves both $A$ and $A'$ fixed.   The notation for the elements of $\psi_1$ are confusing.  $h, a$ are elements of $H, A$ respectively, then when it says $(h)\psi_1$ leaves $A'$ to $A'$, what about $(h)\psi_1$ where it sends $A$ to $Ah.$  Also in the case of $A$ to $Ah$, does it mean $a\mapsto ah?$   Other points of confusion for me is how do both $\sigma, (a)\psi_1$ and $\sigma, (h)\psi_1$ commute, lastly, how does $(a)\psi_2=\sigma^{-1}((a)\psi_1)\sigma=(a)\sigma_1.$   Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wrote out the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3608316/742). Does it help?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719742/need-help-understanding-a-proof-on-if-a-homomorphism-in-textbfgrp-is-not-on) where I asked about the contrapositive.  I am struggling to work out But does $\sigma^{-1}(hxh'')=\sigma^{-1}(h)\sigma^{-1}(xh'')?$  I think in that post, this one, and the one you are posted about.  I am unsure about the conjugation by permutation bit.  For this one, the paper I retyped out, the notation is super confusing.

Comment: Don't use comments to ask questions about *other* posts.

Comment: The paper uses suffix notation (functions follow their arguments). You seem to have completely misunderstood the nature of the objects in question. For example, "in the case of $A$ to $Ah$, does that mean $a\mapsto ah$?" seems to completely misunderstand what the objects you are acting on are. You are acting on **cosets**, not on elements. The action induces a permutation, like all actions. Do you understand what a group action is?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you mean maps of the form $\phi_a:G\to G$ defined by for all $a\in G,$ (G being a group) $\phi_a(x)=ax$?  I looked up the group actions axiom, I am not sure how to apply it to the conjugating function $\psi_1$

Comment: No, I mean **group actions**, exactly what I said. A group acting on a set. This whole proof is based on actions of a group on a set. If you don't know what a group action *is*, then there is no point in you reading (or anyone trying to explain to you) the proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I learned my abstract algebra from Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text.  He doesn't mention group actions.  I am not sure if what he does covered equal to all the standard material for group actions.

Comment: You need more than just looking up the definition. You need to understand what a group action is, and how they relate to morphisms into permutation groups. Until you do, this proof is beyond you. If you haven't learned group actions, then you will need to cease and desist trying to understand this proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I understood the proof why every group $G$ is isomorphic to a group of permutation.  In that proof, Hungerford uses the notation $\phi_a(a)=ax.$  He made mention about how any homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group of permutations is called a representation of $G.$

Comment: You are not listening. This proof relies on an understanding of group actions: a group acting on a set. You do not have that understanding. You do not even know what a group action is. That means that you lack the prerequisites to understand this proof. Nobody can explain this proof to you: it would be like trying to explain a Russian text to you, in russian, when you don't know russian. You need to stop, and learn about group actions first.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin even if I understand group action, the suffix notation is confusing.  In both $(a)\psi_1$ and $(h)\psi_1,$  $a, h$ are arguments in the function $\psi_1,$ while $A$ and $Ah$ are sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Before I brought my questions on here, I asked math grad students helping me to decipher the proof, they can not make heads and take out of the $\psi_1$ function and  how it is being defined.

Comment: The reason you are confused is simply that you do not understand what a group action is. The fact that $A$ and $Ah$ are sets would be utterly irrelevant if you actually knew about group actions. I repeat: you lack the prerequisites to understand the proof. Until you acquire them, you need to stop wasting your time and the time of anyone who tries to help you. That you lack the prerequisites is not a criticism: we all lack the knowledge to understand *most* proofs out there.

Comment: Suffix notation is strange the first time you encounter it. It takes getting used to. But you need to stop trying to blame other things for your confusion. There is no one to blame: you just don't know enough basic material to understand tjis proof. Instead of trying to blame the notation, go try to learn that material. It will be more effective and useful.